# How to get nextPageToken

Tags: php, google-people-api

I'm trying to add pagination to my code after retrieving the contacts using Google's People API.

I've tested it with `pagesize => 1` but I struggle to get "nextPageToken" to be able to go to the next record.

I got no idea how to get "nextPageToken"

Reason why I want that to be done is I got over 4000 contacts but can only get the first 1000 contacts, so I need to be able to goto the next 1000 contacts.

```
session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig('MyloginKey.json');

$redirect_uri = 'localhost';

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");

$client->addScope('profile');

$client->addScope('email');

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');




if (isset($_GET['oauth'])) {

    // Start auth flow by redirecting to Google's auth server

    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

} else if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

    // Receive auth code from Google, exchange it for an access token, and redirect to your base URL

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

} else if ($_SESSION['access_token']) {

    // You have an access token; use it to call the People API

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

 $service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);


    // $PageToken="GgYKAggFEAI";
    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 1,
        'personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
        'sortOrder' => 'FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING',
        // 'pageToken' => 'nextPageToken',
    );
    $connections = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);


    echo "<br>";
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($optParams);
    echo '</pre>';


    foreach ($connections as $connection) {
        if (!empty($connection->getNames()[0])) {
            echo $connection->getNames()[0]->getDisplayName() . "\n" . '<br>';
            if (!empty($connection->getphoneNumbers()[0])) {
                echo $connection->getphoneNumbers()[0]->getcanonicalForm() . "\n" . '<br>';
            } else {
                echo "0";
                echo "<br>";
            }
            if (!empty($connection->getemailAddresses()[0])) {
                echo $connection->getemailAddresses()[0]->getvalue() . "\n" . '<br>';
            } else {
                echo "0";
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
} else {

    $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/?oauth';

    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Manage to figure it out, please see correction down here

```
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 1000,
    'personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
    'sortOrder' => 'FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING',
    'pageToken' => 'PASTE YOUR NEXT TOKEN HERE',
    //  'requestSyncToken' => 'true',
);
$connections = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);


echo $token = $connections->getnextPageToken(); echo "<br>"; //GET NEXT TOKEN
echo $contactsTotal = $connections->gettotalItems(); echo "<br>"; //GET TOTAL CONTACTS
```

Comment: Hi! I'm glad that you managed to solve your problem. Dont forget to accept your answer so we can know that this question is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: yeah at the time when posting my answer i had to wait 24hr to accept my answer, not sure why the wait?